# Find row count of consecutive used cells below a range

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a named range in a sheet.  I need to count the number of consecutive rows with a value directly below the range.  I tried this:

```
endRow = Range("MyRange").End(xlDown).Row
```

This works well unless there are no rows below the range, in which case it returns the last row in the sheet (1048576).  Is there a better approach I can use?

Comment: Use math, not the Excel object model. Find the last row with data in the sheet, then subtract the last row number of the named range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of what you want to do doesn't quite match your line of code but something like this should work:

```
With Range("MyRange")
    endRow = IIf(Len(.Offset(1, 0)) = 0, .End(xlDown).Row, .Row)
End With
```

...assuming "MyRange" is a single-cell range, not multi-row etc